# GetTokenInformation returns ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

The code below returns an `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` error:

```
DWORD dwReturnedDataSize;
if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken,TokenPrivileges,NULL,0,&dwReturnedDataSize))
{
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    return false; 
}
```

I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you have called the function in the mode where it tells you how many bytes you need to retrieve the underlying Token Information data for this handle.  You now need to make a second call using the returned datalength and a buffer of at least that size.

[Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are helpful.

> ReturnLength [out]
>
> A pointer to a variable that receives the number of
> bytes needed for the buffer pointed to by the TokenInformation
> parameter. If this value is larger than the value specified in the
> TokenInformationLength parameter, the function fails and stores no
> data in the buffer.