# GetTokenInformation returns ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER in the first call

Tags: c++

From the MS docs i read that you should call the func twice, first time is to get the token length and the second is getting its info. My problem is that it fails in the first call(error 122) but still writes a length of 32.

```
const char*  CSystemHelper::ReturnUserByProcessHandle(const PROCESSENTRY32 &PENTRY) {

    HANDLE hToken, tHandle;
    DWORD ErrorCode;

    if ((tHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, PENTRY.th32ProcessID)) == 0) {
        ErrorCode = GetLastError();
        CMessage::DEFAULT_MESSAGE(ErrorCode);
        return "UNIDENTIFIED";
    }

    if (!OpenProcessToken(tHandle, TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken)) {
        ErrorCode = GetLastError();
        CMessage::DEFAULT_MESSAGE(ErrorCode);
        return "UNIDENTIFIED";
    }
    
    DWORD len = 0;
// this call fails, but len is set to 32 
    if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenOwner, NULL, 0, &len)) {
        ErrorCode = GetLastError();
        CMessage::DEFAULT_MESSAGE(ErrorCode);
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return "UNIDENTIFIED";
    }

    PTOKEN_OWNER TOKENOWNER = (PTOKEN_OWNER)LocalAlloc(LPTR, len);

    if (!TOKENOWNER) {
        LocalFree(TOKENOWNER);
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return "UNIDENTIFIED";
    }

    if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenOwner, TOKENOWNER, len, &len)) {
        LocalFree(TOKENOWNER);
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return "UNIDENTIFIED";
    }

    char Username[256] = { 0 }, LocalDomain[256] = { 0 };
    DWORD UsernameLength = 256, LocalDomainLength = 256;
    SID_NAME_USE SIDNAMEUSE;

    if (!LookupAccountSidA(NULL, TOKENOWNER->Owner, Username, &UsernameLength, LocalDomain, &LocalDomainLength, &SIDNAMEUSE)){
        LocalFree(TOKENOWNER);
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return "UNIDENTIFIED";
    }

    return Username;
}
```

if that matters handle is opened through a processentry which does not raise any errors

Comment: This sounds like that's exacly what's to be expected, but I don't find it written explicitly in the docs. Does everything else work, if you ignore the return value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GetTokenInformation returns ERROR\_INSUFFICIENT\_BUFFER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073345/gettokeninformation-returns-error-insufficient-buffer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is normal operation.

When TokenInformation parameter is null, GetTokenInformation function returns 122(ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER).

So your code must be changed like this.

```
DWORD len = 0;
// this call fails, but len is set to 32 
    if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenOwner, NULL, 0, &len)) {
        ErrorCode = GetLastError();
        if (ErrorCode != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER || len == 0)
        {
                CMessage::DEFAULT_MESSAGE(ErrorCode);
                CloseHandle(hToken);
                return "UNIDENTIFIED";
        }
    }

    PTOKEN_OWNER TOKENOWNER = (PTOKEN_OWNER)LocalAlloc(LPTR, len);

    if (!TOKENOWNER) {
        LocalFree(TOKENOWNER);
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return "UNIDENTIFIED";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying. Combining answers of Jack Lee and Karsten Loop i came to solution. I tried to omit error checking and return username but it was pure garbage so i decided to use std::string instead of c-style char arrays and everything is working.